# How to convert Caffe trained model and parameters to directly be used for inference in caffe2?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, inference, caffe2

I have a trained caffe model on a CPU desktop. I want to port it mobile platform to do inference using Caffe2. Any insights into how should I go about with it? Do the scripts that are provided by Caffe2 allow for conversion of the model and reuse of the weights? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: It is a ResNet101 Model !!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps mentioned in the below link:
https://caffe2.ai/docs/caffe-migration.html#caffe-to-caffe2

Its pretty clear. Make sure your protobuf version is up-to-date before running the caffe_translator script.

Good Luck !!